# Setting the Maximum Message Size for JMS Destinations in Payara

Tags: jms, payara, asadmin

We are using a Payara Server Version 5 and 6 on which we have several JMS Destinations configured.
These are configured via the asadmin command line tool like so:

```
./asadmin --Port=4848 create-jms-resource 
--resType=javax.jms.Queue
--property=Name=lokal.test
--force=false 
--enabled=true jms/transport/test
```

I now have the problem that I need to configure the Maximum Message Size for this JMS destination because the default value is too small. (Default on payara is 10MB)
This should be done with the asadmin command line tool. Using the GUI is not an option because I need to automate the behavior.

I already tried setting the property `MaxBytesPerMsg` to -1 (unlimited) to try this out. (According to https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/5.0/reference-manual.pdf Page 137)
This however did nothing even after restarting the payara. The value was still set to 10MB.

Using the imqcmd (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5166/6mbb1kq38/index.html) could be possible but would be a problem because we would need to deploy this tool on multiple servers.

I expect that there is some possibility to set this property using the asadmin tool especially using the properties of the JMS destination similar to this:
`set resources.admin-object-resource.jms/transport/test.property.MaxBytesPerMsg=-1`

However I can't seem to find the appropriate property name.

Does anyone know of a way to do this using the asadmin command line tool?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!